# Delphi/FMX and iOS crash reports: how to use crash reports to find a bug in the source code?

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, firemonkey, crash-reports

My firemonkey app is in the App Store for three days and now i have a first crash reports. How i can use the crash report provided in Xcode organizer to determine errors in my delphi source code?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. You might want to try this: https://blog.grijjy.com/2017/02/09/build-your-own-error-reporter-part-1-ios/

Comment: @DaveNottage Thank You, Dave, it looks very promising!